# Typescript executing toString on a Function results in weird characters (path_1, (0, promises.writeFile))

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to convert a function into a string to send it to a worker thread and execute it there. However, the string contains weird chars where imported code is used.

```
import { HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { access, constants, writeFile } from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';
import { Error as CustomError } from 'src/util/Error';
import { AbstractTask } from 'src/util/queue/AbstractTask';

export class CreateFileTask extends AbstractTask<boolean> {
    private path: string;

    private buffer: Buffer;

    constructor(path: string, buffer: Buffer) {
        super();

        this.path = path;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public async execute(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let resolvedPath = path.resolve(this.path);

            try {
                await access(resolvedPath, constants.F_OK);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(new CustomError(`file at ${this.path} already exists`, HttpStatus.CONFLICT));
            }

            try {
                await writeFile(resolvedPath, this.buffer);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof Error) {
                    reject(new CustomError(e.message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                } else {
                    reject(new CustomError(e as string, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                }
            }

            resolve(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Calling `new CreateFileTask(...).execute.toString()` results in weird chars:

```
execute() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let resolvedPath = path.resolve(this.path);
        try {
            await (0, promises_1.access)(resolvedPath, promises_1.constants.F_OK);
        }
        catch (e) {
            reject(new Error_1.Error(`file at ${this.path} already exists`, common_1.HttpStatus.CONFLICT));
        }
        try {
            await (0, promises_1.writeFile)(resolvedPath, this.buffer);
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof Error) {
                reject(new Error_1.Error(e.message, common_1.HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
            }
            else {
                reject(new Error_1.Error(e, common_1.HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
            }
        }
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

Using `import * as path from "path"` does seem to fix it for the path module. Why is that? Is there any other solution instead of using the `import * as ... from ...` aka importing *everthing* even if not needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "weird characters" are the compiled version of your code that is output of your bundler, and what actually executes. But that's not the real problem here.

---

> I am trying to convert a function into a string to send it to a worker thread and execute it there.

You *cannot* convert a function to a string an expect it to be executable on the other side. So, do not try encode functions and pass them as strings.

In order for you to send a function to execute, you'd need to send any values used in that function from the scope of that function. And that's not really practical.

For example:

```
const foo = 123
function logFoo() { console.log(foo) }
console.log(logFoo.toString()) // "function logFoo() { console.log(foo) }"
```

Here `logFoo` is converted to a string just fine, but it references a local variable `foo` which is *not included* in the output string. So this will likely crash if you try to `eval` and run it.

This problem is much worse if you have imports from other files, or a class reference like `this.something`.

So this approach just isn't going to work. Do not do this.

---

Instead, load your code into the worker, then post messages to it that contain the *data* itself.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. However, I am not certain what you mean by "load your code into your worker". Do you mean declaring the function in the source file for the worker instead of sending it to the worker? Because that would not an be option for me, I need to be able to execute any given function on the worker. How would one achieve that if its not possible to send a function to the worker (because any item in the transferList of postMessage gets cloned with the structuredClone algortihm and therefore functions end up as strings)?

Comment: "I need to be able to execute any given function on the worker" That's not how it works, you can't do that. The worker should have code that in it already, then you `postMessage()` with some data that the worker handles with `worker.on('message', () => { ... })`. Workers are standalone applications that you can exchange data with.

Comment: Would dynamically executing any function in the background be possible with child processes? There has to be some way of doing this in nodejs, right? Basically I am looking for the js pedant to javas `new Thread(() -> ...)`

Comment: Nope, a child process wouldn't help you here. Javascript is *fundamentally* single threaded. Workers are a work around for that, but workers are just their own instance of a javascript engine running in it's own thread. The worker APIs allow you pass data to/from workers. You _cannot_ pass an execution context to/from a worker. You have to architect your application to use workers this way. Think of the worker as a server, and you main thread as a client. You can't just send a function to the server to execute.